# surround planets (points) groups on a map (Canvas)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Hello i am using actually CANVAS Drawing on javascript.

I have a bench of points, which represent planets :
I know how to do : with canvas.context(2d) or P5.Js librairie ...

[image]

But do you see the blue or red lines ? it creates "packets" or "zone" or "territory".

I have absoluly no idea how to programm this, which mathematics concepts behind ....someone can push me on the rails ? I don't know how to call this in english too ....

Edit :

I want something similar at the end

[image]

Best regards

Comment: what do you catually need to do? create this image on canvas? do you always have two groups of colors? you should had more details to the question

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: I want to have a canvas with point representing a planet .and grouped by color faction. You can lost or win planets on the galaxy map....it is for a warhammer 40k campaign map. I want create an influence area around all planet

Comment: Maybe you can start by connecting all the points of the same color - then zoom out the line that creates a connection?

Comment: Connecting point is not a problem, i know how to do. But create an line all around is difficilt

Comment: @BaptisteBauer isn't the wh40k map placed on hexagons? Can you show a screenshot of something similar?

Comment: "Connecting point is not a problem, i know how to do". Please show this part.

Comment: The question is not about draw stroke between point , but create an area around an array of point

Comment: might be a bit of a left field idea, but could you get a similar effect by adapting [metaballs](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/ISPozOLXW) ? (e.g. encapsulate the example to a class that use a single p5.Image and points, change the rendering so you can get a tighter threshold and specify which background/fill you want, then re-use two instances, one for each set of points). It might not be super accurate, but hopefully a decent enough approximation ?

Comment: I guess that your planets do not collide but I created something using [metaballs](https://editor.p5js.org/KonradLinkowski/sketches/1_zFFQQtg) you can see

Comment: Take a look at Voronoi cells.

Comment: Look very complicated and out of my level :/ 

Let Try Hard

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I tried to do it using voronoi but I guess that I'm missing something https://codepen.io/KonradLinkowski/pen/ExRqdVL?editors=0010

Comment: Here's [an article about the Vonoroi approach](https://community.precisely.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=19&MessageKey=d032b85a-c902-472b-a326-a51e8d495d5a&CommunityKey=fe4d1ee2-f1c6-4307-87d2-00bea1344885&ReturnUrl=%2Fcommunities%2Fcommunity-home%2Fdigestviewer%3FListKey%3Da5a2f6cc-8392-4e74-81fa-77b1aaf17350#bmd032b85a-c902-472b-a326-a51e8d495d5a) which may be helpful